# Using a user's Oauth token to get LinkedIn data about their connections

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) shows a list of fields returned for Sign In with LinkedIn.  Can these fields be returned for a user's connections or only that user?

Comment: Did you ever find out a solution to this? Looking for something similar.

Comment: no, linkedin's api is closed off @Sunny